# Kafka max.in.flight.request.per.connection

Tags: apache-kafka

I read in Kafka Definitive Guide that **setting max.in.flight.request.per.connection to some higher value decreases the throughput**.
**Could some one please help explain how does the throughput decrease**? For ex:- if max.in.flight.requests.per.connection is set to 5 then it means that a producer can send 5 messages at once to the broker. So increase in this value would increase concurrent messages sent to the broker and it would also increase the throughput too. But my understanding seems to be wrong somewhere. Can some one please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests != messages. A producer request is a batch of messages.

More batches means more network packets to maintain and track. Acking each message in all batches causes lower throughput. You could disable acks, but then you open yourself to the possibility of data loss

Also, I don't think that guide yet discusses idempotent producers, which requires a max of 5 in-flight requests, and for latest release of Kafka, is enabled by default